# Mvc Identity 2.0 with AngularJs

Tags: c#, angularjs, razor, model-view-controller, single-page-application

i have a razor syntax who verify that user is administrator, and inside it i want to add a angular syntax who display all users with roles, but if i do that ,the page doesn't display anything, if I put angular syntax outside of razor, it works but everybody can see the users ...

```
<div class="container">

    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("administrator"))
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in usersAndRolesList | filter : search">
                <td style="padding-top:17px;width:50%">{{item.username}}</td>
                <td style="padding-top:17px;width:30%">{{item.roles}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn" style="background-color:transparent"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> </button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn" style="background-color:transparent"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you do open only one "{" but close "}" twice at the end? Check the vailidity of the HTML returned by the server by using the "view source" feature of the browser first.

Comment: No, i add one more  "}" at the end only when i copied here...